# Телеграмм не отправляет запрос через webhook

Tags: php, telegram

При отправке сообщения боту не отправляется запрос через webhook.
Webhook успешно установил, у домена есть SSL-сертификат от Let's Encrypt, рейтинг А.

getWebhookInfo выдает следующую ошибку

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://сайт/index.php","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":22,"last_error_date":1568020905,"last_error_message":"Connection timed out","max_connections":40}}
```

Сам код

```
const TOKEN = 'токен';
const URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.TOKEN.'/';

$update = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);



function sendRequest($method, $params = []){

    if(!empty($params)){
        $url = URL.$method.'?'.http_build_query($params);
    } else{
        $url = URL.$method;
    }

    return json_decode(file_get_contents($url), JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);
}


$chat_id = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];

sendRequest('sendMessage', ['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => 'Текст']);
```

Comment: а сервер где установлен, в России?
тогда работать не будет. все вопросы в РосКомНадзор.

Comment: хостинг jino, скорее всего сервера в российском ДЦ. Спасибо, понял

Comment: Да, хочу узнать, такая-же проблема.